# Help understanding why we can't treat lines as circles in a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the complex function $e^{-z^2}$. Since it is holomorphic everywhere for any closed circle with finite radius $\gamma$ we have that.

$$\int_\gamma e^{-z^2}dz=0$$

I was wondering why if we now consider a circle with infinite radius e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ that we now have a non-zero result.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}dz=\sqrt\pi$$

My first idea why this might be is if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a circle, the interior would be the upper half plane hence when considering the contour we obtain a singularity at $\infty$. The only issue is that this singularity has a residue of $\text{Res}[e^{-z^2},\infty]=\text{Res}[e^{-1/z^2},0]=0$ since $e^{-1/z^2}=1+\mathcal{O}(1/z^2)$.

The other idea I had was to suppose that lines are not closed contours e.g. there are no closed parameterizations $[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The closest I could come up with was $\tan:(-\pi/2, \pi/2)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ but that only excludes the points at infinity in the complex plane. So then I considered that by skipping the point at complex-infinity we are somehow obtaining the $\sqrt\pi$ term.

Any help understanding is greatly appriciated.

Comment: On the Riemann sphere, the real line is a great circle with one point missing, and that one point is the north pole (north pole = $\infty$, south pole = $0$).  So integrating on the real line is not integrating on a closed contour that has $\infty$ in its interior.  Would you try to integrate $1/(z-1)^2$ around the unit circle (centered at $0$) with the point $z = 1$ omitted by using a residue at $z = 1$?

Comment: This is a very satisfactory explanation, thanks. If you post this as a solution I will accept it.